# Python syntax error using 'with'

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to compile a project but I'm getting a invalid syntax error during tests with arrow point at the 'h' in with. I haven't written the code and it is fairly years old.

```
d = Gnuplot.Data(pnts,title=im_title,with='candlesticks')
```

I tried changing `with` to something else but then I got different errors. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: `with` is a Python keyword.

Comment: `with` is a reserved word for Python interpreter. Without error traceback we can't say anything about "different errors".

Comment: I doubt this class constructor uses `with` as a keyword argument, because `with` is a Python keyword. Double-check the API.

Comment: `with_` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this code was written before `with` became one of the [reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=with#keywords).

<strike>The (possible) workaround:</strike>

```
d = Gnuplot.Data(pnts, **{'title': im_title, 'with': 'candlesticks'})
```

Just checked, it won't work - [they were using `with` as a variable name extensively](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot-py/code/298/tree/trunk/PlotItems.py#l86) until [Gnuplot.py 1.8](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot-py/news/2008/05/gnuplotpy-version-18-released/).

The solution for Gnuplot.py 1.8+ is to use `with_` argument:

```
d = Gnuplot.Data(pnts, title=im_title, with_='candlesticks')
```

Comment: "A couple years" is therefore more like [ten years](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Answer (score 3):

In PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code, the following guidance appears in the section [Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) :

> single_trailing_underscore_ : used by convention to avoid conflicts
>   with Python keyword

i.e.:

```
d = Gnuplot.Data(pnts,title=im_title,with_='candlesticks')
```